Is it a good idea to replace "part" of the H1 with an image via a pseudo element?
The client wants their minimalist logo version to replace the abbreviation of their company name every time it appears on their headings.
For example, if the heading says "You Can Make It Work With [company name]". The [company name] will be there, but overlaid with their logo.
What I'm thinking of doing is something like this:
<style>
h1 span {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 span:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color:red;
  background-image: url(https://placehold.co/150x40);
  bottom: 0;
}
</style>

<h1>
This an H1 heading. This <span>Logo</span> is inside the H1.
</h1>

You can see it live here: https://jsfiddle.net/daneloctober/pomuygcq/
Is this valid? I mean, will they not get penalized for this?

Yes, your solution is more than ok.
The main thing is to use alt tags and it is desirable that the title (the name of the image file, too, was readable).
There should be no penalties from search engines.

I was trying to go for a very easy solution (pure CSS) so the client can have it easy, but I think I'll just go with building a shortcode (WordPress) that inserts an actual image, and then I can use an alt tag, instead of the pseudo code with the background image. Thanks for your help!

There is no reason to be penalized for it.
But you should be aware that you are removing the company name as a keyword from H1. If you want to solve it (almost partially), you may add the company name to the alt and title attributes of the image, or you may include the company name in the title tag of the page.

Hmm.. well the thing is, i'm adding it as a background instead of an img element, so that it's a purely CSS solution without having to add the actual image.. BUT I realize, i can just add an inline image with an ALT tag i guess...
